# Setting ipopt options through pyomo

Tags: python-3.x, pyomo, ipopt

I am having trouble setting the ipopt options through pyomo.

For some options one can simply use

```
executable = os.getcwd()+'/Ipopt/Ipopt/build/bin/ipopt.exe'
opt = SolverFactory("ipopt", executable=executable,solver_io='nl')
opt.options['nlp_scaling_method'] = 'user-scaling'
```

This works fine. If i try set the option for "fixed_variable_treatment", i.e.:

```
opt.options['fixed_variable_treatment'] = 'make_parameter'
```

i get the following error:

```
ERROR: "[base]\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", 599, solve
        Solver (asl) returned non-zero return code (1)
ERROR: "[base]\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", 604, solve
        Solver log:
        Unknown keyword "fixed_variable_treatment"
```

I am assuming that this is because you cannot set all of the options through python?

Any help or way to overcome this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The workaround is to use an ipopt.opt file as described at https://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node35.html. The option file is placed in the current working directory where IPOPT is called.

Gabe Hackebeil responded on the [Github issue](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/206):

> The default behavior is to send options to Ipopt through the command
> line, but not all Ipopt options are available through the command
> line. This is probably one of them. Historically one would place this
> kind of option in an options file named "ipopt.opt" in the working
> directory, and Ipopt would pick it up automatically.
>
> Very recently I added functionality to the Ipopt interface in Pyomo to
> write an options file for you. Options that begin with "OF_" will be
> placed in a temporary options file (with that prefix removed). I don't
> know if this has made it into a release yet.

**EDIT**:  Be aware that as of Pyomo version 6.4.1, if you specify options using the "OF_" prefix, then if you have an existing `ipopt.opt` file in your working directory, it will be ignored and the file created using the "OF_" options will be used instead.  i.e. the options specified using "OF_" are not appended - they're used instead of.

Comment: Thank you very much for creating a Github issue regarding this! I did figure it would be something along these lines. Will try the suggest workarounds and see what happens.

Comment: The OF_ trick made it to release and it works. Just use "OF_fixed_variable_treatment".